# C++ get SQL_VARCHAR?

Tags: c++, sql, json, string

I am trying to read an big string from an sql database. The sql type is SQL_VARCHAR. Which type I have to choose in c++ to store the response?

My string is an JSON Object, which I want to parse later on. But this is step two. Unfortunetely I am not
even able to store the database response. The other integer types are stored properly.

```
CString test;
SQLGetData(sqlStmtHandle, 18, SQL_VARCHAR, &test, sizeof(test), NULL);
```

Comment: See __Retrieving Variable-Length Data in Parts__ from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlgetdata-function?view=sql-server-ver15  _"...SQLGetData can be used to retrieve data from a column that contains variable-length data in parts - that is, when the identifier of the SQL data type of the column is SQL_CHAR, __SQL_VARCHAR__..."_

Comment: If I understand the article correctly, you suggest to split the data into parts, right? Isn't there any way to "download" the data in a string variable? The string should be able to allocate as much storage as needed and my response isnt greater than 50 MB..

Comment: If you know the size (or the maximum possible size) then `std::string str(known_size, 0);` and pass `str.data()` (or `&str[0]`) into `SQLGetData` together with it's size.